# How to simplify the OR conditions in SQL statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following Oracle query to return me a list of book names.

```
Select bookName From Books
       Where bookName = "A" 
             OR bookName = "B"
             OR bookName = "C"
```

**What I think:**

Instead of repeating **OR bookName = "blah"**, make this simple to just have one line statement but same logic.

First of all, create a **bookName.txt** with the following values

- A
- B
- C

Then in the SQL statement, make this book name as an argument,

```
Select bookName From Books
       Where bookName= "$values"
```

I 'm not sure if we can achieve it in this way. The reason I want to do this way is that I have hundreds of book names and I don't want the sql statement to be super long. Can someone please enlight me the direction?

Comment: If you have hundreds of these values then you can put them in a table and join against that table.

Comment: First of load your **bookName.txt** data into one table, and then use that table in join query.

Comment: This means the table will be created each time I update my book name list?

Comment: @Juergend, This means the table will be created each time I update my book name list?

Comment: The table will be filled each time you update the book list. How often do you have to do that?

Comment: For this purpose I sometimes use global temporary tables. Insert the filter values there and then use them as correct filter. But you have to be careful because the optimizer doesn't estimate correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IN if number of values is limited. Your example would look like this:

```
Select bookName From Books
   Where bookName in ('A','B','C');
```

If you want to use bind variables and select up to 10 books (here limitation is crucial and can't be very big number) you can use something like this:

```
Select bookName From Books
   Where bookName in (:p1,:p2,:p3,:p4,:p5,:p6,:p7,:p8,:p9,:p10);
```

In this case you bind first N params to set known values, leaving rest params equal to NULL.

If number of input values need to be unrestricted then you can use temp table; pre-fill it with simple inserts and then use join with it in your sql.

```
-- create once your temp table. It is not part of your PL/SQL code.
create global temporary table tmp$books(book_name);


-- in your procedure calling sql prepopulate temp table with values:
LOOP
  -- looping through your values
  insert into tmp$books values(:p); 
END LOOP;


Select b.bookName 
  From Books b
  inner join tmp$books t
     on b.book_name = t.book_name
;
```

Commit/Rollback at the end to delete all temp values.

Answer (score 0):

Created an account just so I could upvote Rusty. IN statement was what worked for me since I was trying to add a bunch of OR statements that were all in the same column. Cleans it up a lot.

```
Where bookName = "A" 
             OR bookName = "B"
             OR bookName = "C"
```

Becomes

```
WHERE bookName IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

So much cleaner! Especially in my case where it was 11 or statements from a rather long column name.